# Add auto value using loop into array

Tags: php

I am using my array and want to add auto value how can i add pls see my code

```
$i=1;

$data = array(
    "s_no" => $i,
    "bui"=>$builderprojects_ary->__get('bui_id'),
    "bui"=>$builder_name,
    "bui_image"=>$builderprojects_ary->__get('project_image'),


);


$builder_projects_arr_obj[] = $data;
$i++;
```

I am getting result like

```
"data": [
    {
        "s_no": 1,
        "builder_project_id": "389",
        "builder_name": "Sidhartha Build Home",
        "builder_project_image": null,

    },
    {
        "s_no": 1,
        "builder_project_id": "388",
        "builder_name": "Orris Group",
        "builder_project_image": null,

    },
```

Expecting result

```
"data": [
    {
        "s_no": 1,
        "builder_project_id": "389",
        "builder_name": "Sidhartha Build Home",
        "builder_project_image": null,

    },
    {
        "s_no": 2,
        "builder_project_id": "388",
        "builder_name": "Orris Group",
        "builder_project_image": null,

    },
```

New user in php pls guide thanx a ton in advance

want to populate s_no auto matically

Comment: pls dont do i am new user in here

Comment: See @PRANAV's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a loop structure in your code, so it seems you're only adding one item to the `$data` array.

In that case, if you increment `$i` with `$i++`, it is done *after* the creation of the array. The next time you add something, the counter should be ok.

To increment the value *before* adding the data into the array, use `++$i`.

Comment: ++$i? where to use if i use in array it will produce one increment value in all iteration

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"s_no" => $i` with `"s_no" => $i++` and remove `$i++` in last line.